# Manejo del Combobox con AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy tratando de desarrollar unas funcionalidades en un combobox usando el lenguaje de AngularJs y estoy recibiendo diversos problemas / errores.

1 . Se trata de hacer un combobox que se rellene con un Array [] de
naciones. **( Esto ya funciona )**

**2  Por defecto debe salir marcada la nación a la que pertenece el**
cliente, en caso cliente, que ponga selecciona una ( No lo consigo )

```
        // Se obtiene la nacion del cliente
        $scope.nacionClienteOriginal = "-- Seleccione --";
        if ($scope.nacionalidad != undefined ){
            if ($scope.nacionalidad != null ){
                // Voy comprobando que no me de error por el camino.
                if ($scope.nacionalidad.descripcion != null && $scope.nacionalidad.descripcion != '' && $scope.nacionalidad.descripcion != 'null'){ 
                    $scope.nacionClienteOriginal = $scope.nacionalidad.descripcion;
                }
            }
        }
```

Aquí voy comprobando que no "pete" por el camino y finalmente me sale que el cliente es de España.

Ahora cuando voy a ponerlo por defecto en el combobox en el que aparecen 260 Nacionalidades:

```
 input.form-control(id="nacionalidadComb",name="nacionalidadComb",mp-select,ng-model="listaNaciones",mp-select-options="option.descripcion for option in listaNaciones", ng-init="nacionClienteOriginal", ng-change="cambiarNacion(option);" ng-disabled="disabledNacionalidadComb")
```

Como se puede ver tengo el `ng-init` y En vez de seleccionarse España entre el listado de naciones, me saca el siguiente texto el comboBox: `choose among the following`

¿ Podrían ayudarme ? muchas gracias.